# Angular 9 Unwanted redirect after page reload

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have problems to understand the Angular router behaviour. Currently, the routing module looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: ManageCompetitionComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: ':eventID',
            component: EventProfileComponent,
        },
    ],
}];
```

When I open `http://localhost:4200/admin/competition` and click a link that navigates to `http://localhost:4200/admin/competition/1234` it works fine and the `EventProfileComponent` is shown as part of `ManageCompetitionComponent` (contains a router-outlet).

But when I call now from **browser** (e.g. refresh/F5):

```
http://localhost:4200/admin/competition         -> works fine
http://localhost:4200/admin/competition/1234    -> redirects to /admin/competition
```

So how can I prevent that redirect?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: ManageCompetitionComponent,
   
}, 
{
    path: ':eventID',
    component: EventProfileComponent,
}];
```